# Carousel que passa uma imagem por vez e com miniaturas embaixo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, carousel

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu encontrei um exemplo e estava tentando modificar para o que eu preciso. Eu preciso que a imagem exibida no carrossel e as miniaturas sejam maiores que o exemplo que encontrei, mas quando tento modificar para  imagem do carrossel ficar maior uma imagem sobrepõe a outra.

***HTML***

```
<title>Featured Content Slider</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-easing-1.3.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-easing-compatibility.1.2.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/coda-slider.1.1.1.pack.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var theInt = null;
    var $crosslink, $navthumb;
    var curclicked = 0;

    theInterval = function(cur){
        clearInterval(theInt);

        if( typeof cur != 'undefined' )
            curclicked = cur;

        $crosslink.removeClass("active-thumb");
        $navthumb.eq(curclicked).parent().addClass("active-thumb");
            $(".stripNav ul li a").eq(curclicked).trigger('click');

        theInt = setInterval(function(){
            $crosslink.removeClass("active-thumb");
            $navthumb.eq(curclicked).parent().addClass("active-thumb");
            $(".stripNav ul li a").eq(curclicked).trigger('click');
            curclicked++;
            if( 6 == curclicked )
                curclicked = 0;

        }, 3000);
    };

    $(function(){

        $("#main-photo-slider").codaSlider();

        $navthumb = $(".nav-thumb");
        $crosslink = $(".cross-link");

        $navthumb
        .click(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            theInterval($this.parent().attr('href').slice(1) - 1);
            return false;
        });

        theInterval();
    });
</script>
```

```
<div id="page-wrap">

<div class="slider-wrap">
    <div id="main-photo-slider" class="csw">
        <div class="panelContainer">

            <div class="panel" title="Panel 1">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <img src="images/tempphoto-1.jpg" alt="temp" />
                    <div class="photo-meta-data">
                        Photo Credit: <a href="http://flickr.com/photos/astrolondon/2396265240/">Kaustav Bhattacharya</a><br />
                        <span>"Free Tibet" Protest at the Olympic Torch Rally</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel" title="Panel 2">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <img src="images/tempphoto-2.jpg" alt="temp" />
                    <div class="photo-meta-data">
                        Chicago Bears at Seattle Seahawks<br />
                        <span>Fifth field goal, overtime win for the Seahawks</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>      
            <div class="panel" title="Panel 3">
                <div class="wrapper">

                    <img src="images/scotch-egg.jpg" alt="scotch egg" class="floatLeft"/>

                    <h1>How to Cook a Scotch Egg</h1>

                    <ul>
                        <li>6 hard-boiled eggs, well chilled (i try to cook them to just past soft boiled stage, then stick them in the coldest part of the fridge to firm up)</li>
                        <li>1 pound good quality sausage meat (i used ground turkey meat, seasoned with sage, white pepper, salt and a tiny bit of maple syrup)</li>
                        <li>1/2 cup AP flour</li>
                        <li>1-2 eggs, beaten</li>
                        <li>3/4 cup panko-style bread crumbs</li>
                        <li>Vegetable oil for frying</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel" title="Panel 4">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <img src="images/tempphoto-4.jpg" alt="temp" />
                    <div class="photo-meta-data">
                        A Poem by Shel Silverstein<br />
                        <span>Falling Up</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel" title="Panel 5">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <img src="images/tempphoto-5.jpg" alt="temp" />
                    <div class="photo-meta-data">
                        New Video on CSS-Tricks<br />
                        <span>Using Wufoo for Web Forms</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel" title="Panel 6">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <h1>A Tale of Two Cities</h1>
                    <p><em>Charles Dickins</em></p>
                    <blockquote>It was the best of times, it was the worst of times, it was the age of wisdom, it was the age of foolishness, it was the epoch of belief, it was the epoch of incredulity, it was the season of Light, it was the season of Darkness, it was the spring of hope, it was the winter of despair, we had everything before us, we had nothing before us, we were all going direct to heaven, we were all going direct the other way - in short, the period was so far like the present period, that some of its noisiest authorities insisted on its being received, for good or for evil, in the superlative degree of comparison only.</blockquote>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <a href="#1" class="cross-link active-thumb"><img src="images/tempphoto-1thumb.jpg" class="nav-thumb" alt="temp-thumb" /></a>
    <div id="movers-row">
        <div><a href="#2" class="cross-link"><img src="images/tempphoto-2thumb.jpg" class="nav-thumb" alt="temp-thumb" /></a></div>
        <div><a href="#3" class="cross-link"><img src="images/tempphoto-3thumb.jpg" class="nav-thumb" alt="temp-thumb" /></a></div>
        <div><a href="#4" class="cross-link"><img src="images/tempphoto-4thumb.jpg" class="nav-thumb" alt="temp-thumb" /></a></div>
        <div><a href="#5" class="cross-link"><img src="images/tempphoto-5thumb.jpg" class="nav-thumb" alt="temp-thumb" /></a></div>
        <div><a href="#6" class="cross-link"><img src="images/tempphoto-6thumb.jpg" class="nav-thumb" alt="temp-thumb" /></a></div>
    </div>

</div>

</div>
```

***CSS***

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; } 
body { font-family: Arial, Helvetica, 
sans-serif; font-size: 10px; } 

/* UTILITY STYLES */ 
.floatLeft { float: left; margin-right: 10px;} 
.floatRight { float: right; } 
.clear { clear: both; } 
a { outline: none; } 

/* PAGE STRUCTURE */ 
#page-wrap { width: 500px; margin: 25px auto; position: relative; min-height: 500px; background: url(images/bg.png) top center; } 

/* TYPOGRAPHY */ 
ul { list-style: square inside; } 
a, a:visited { color: #729dff; text-decoration: none; } 
a:hover, a:active { color: white; } 
blockquote { padding: 0 20px; margin-left: 20px; border-left: 20px solid #ccc; font-size: 14px; font-family: Georgia, serif; font-style: italic; margin-top: 10px;} 

/* SLIDER */ 
.slider-wrap { width: 419px; position: absolute; top: 87px; left: 40px; } 
.stripViewer .panelContainer .panel ul { text-align: left; margin: 0 15px 0 30px; } 
.stripViewer { position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 419px; height: 285px; } 
.stripViewer .panelContainer { position: relative; left: 0; top: 0; } 
.stripViewer .panelContainer .panel { float: left; height: 100%; position: relative; width: 419px; } 
.stripNavL, .stripNavR, .stripNav { display: none; } 
.nav-thumb { border: 1px solid black; margin-right: 5px; } 
#movers-row { margin: -43px 0 0 62px; } 
#movers-row div { width: 20%; float: left; } 
#movers-row div a.cross-link { float: right; } 
.photo-meta-data { background: url(images/transpBlack.png); padding: 10px; height: 30px; margin-top: -50px; position: relative; z-index: 9999; color: white; } 
.photo-meta-data span { font-size: 13px; } 
.cross-link { display: block; width: 62px; margin-top: -14px; position: relative; padding-top: 15px; z-index: 9999; } 
.active-thumb { background: transparent url(images/icon-uparrowsmallwhite.png) top center no-repeat; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 
        $('#myCarousel').carousel({
                interval: 5000
        });
 
        $('#carousel-text').html($('#slide-content-0').html());
 
        //Handles the carousel thumbnails
       $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').click( function(){
            var id = this.id.substr(this.id.lastIndexOf("-") + 1);
            var id = parseInt(id);
            $('#myCarousel').carousel(id);
        });
 
 
        // When the carousel slides, auto update the text
        $('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function (e) {
                 var id = $('.item.active').data('slide-number');
                $('#carousel-text').html($('#slide-content-'+id).html());
        });
});
```

```css
.hide-bullets {
list-style:none;
margin-left: -40px;
margin-top:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
        <div id="main_area">
                <!-- Slider -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12" id="slider">
                        <!-- Top part of the slider -->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-8" id="carousel-bounding-box">
                                <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
                                    <!-- Carousel items -->
                                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                                        <div class="active item" data-slide-number="0">
                                        <img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&text=one"></div>

                                        <div class="item" data-slide-number="1">
                                        <img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&text=two"></div>

                                        <div class="item" data-slide-number="2">
                                        <img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&text=three"></div>

                                        <div class="item" data-slide-number="3">
                                        <img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&text=four"></div>

                                        <div class="item" data-slide-number="4">
                                        <img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&text=five"></div>

                                        <div class="item" data-slide-number="5">
                                        <img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&text=six"></div>
                                    </div><!-- Carousel nav -->
                                    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>                                       
                                    </a>
                                    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>                                       
                                    </a>                                
                                    </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-4" id="carousel-text"></div>

                            <div id="slide-content" style="display: none;">
                                <div id="slide-content-0">
                                    <h2>Slider One</h2>
                                    <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
                                    <p class="sub-text">October 24 2014 - <a href="#">Read more</a></p>
                                </div>

                                <div id="slide-content-1">
                                    <h2>Slider Two</h2>
                                    <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
                                    <p class="sub-text">October 24 2014 - <a href="#">Read more</a></p>
                                </div>

                                <div id="slide-content-2">
                                    <h2>Slider Three</h2>
                                    <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
                                    <p class="sub-text">October 24 2014 - <a href="#">Read more</a></p>
                                </div>

                                <div id="slide-content-3">
                                    <h2>Slider Four</h2>
                                    <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
                                    <p class="sub-text">October 24 2014 - <a href="#">Read more</a></p>
                                </div>

                                <div id="slide-content-4">
                                    <h2>Slider Five</h2>
                                    <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
                                    <p class="sub-text">October 24 2014 - <a href="#">Read more</a></p>
                                </div>

                                <div id="slide-content-5">
                                    <h2>Slider Six</h2>
                                    <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
                                    <p class="sub-text">October 24 2014 - <a href="#">Read more</a></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!--/Slider-->

                <div class="row hidden-xs" id="slider-thumbs">
                        <!-- Bottom switcher of slider -->
                        <ul class="hide-bullets">
                            <li class="col-sm-2">
                                <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-0"><img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=one"></a>
                            </li>

                            <li class="col-sm-2">
                                <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-1"><img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=two"></a>
                            </li>

                            <li class="col-sm-2">
                                <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-2"><img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=three"></a>
                            </li>

                            <li class="col-sm-2">
                                <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-3"><img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=four"></a>
                            </li>

                            <li class="col-sm-2">
                                <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-4"><img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=five"></a>
                            </li>

                            <li class="col-sm-2">
                                <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-5"><img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=six"></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>                 
                </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Caso queira o link
https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/7NKkV